# Help needed, following Unity multiplayer Health-Bar tutorial. Only working on Server Host instance of the game

Tags: unity, multiplayer, client-server, unity-networking, synchronization

was really hoping someone can be good enough to look over my code, I've been trying to fix it for several days. I followed the Unity tutorial which is fairly basic but the bit that confuses me (and potentially where the problem lies) is the:

```
 if (!server){return;}
```

part at the top of my TakeDamage() function.

The problem im seeing is that once I get to that part of the tutorial, the bullet fired by the Host is registered against the other player and I can see his health has gone down (great so far!) , but when I load the instance in the editor (i did running another standalone on my laptop and connect to internet matchmaking but the same thing occurs) his bullets are not registered (even though my debug log tells me the Ray did hit the player.

The tutorial tells me to make it return if not server, it then uses [SyncVar] and a hook that is supposed to call the method "OnChangeHealth" whenever currentHealth is changed. 
This DOES NOT appear to be happening, and the TakeDamage code is only happening on the Server-Client-Host instance.

I was trying to adapt the tutorial to my own game, so there are some slight differences in the function and class names, but to me it looks to be exactly the same functionality-wise. I will have to just post my full code here as I don't know which part is causing the issue:

(MANY THANKS FOR READING  AND/OR HELPING):

the Player class:

```
public class Player : NetworkBehaviour {
private GameObject startScreen;
public const int maxHealth = 100;

[SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeHealth")]
public int currentHealth = maxHealth;

private float playerHeight;
private AudioSource audioSource;
public AudioClip painBodySound;
public AudioClip painHeadSound;
public AudioClip painHeadSound2;
public RectTransform healthBar;


void Start () {
    startScreen = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("StartScreen");
    if (startScreen != null)
    {
        startScreen.SetActive(false);
    }
    playerHeight = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.size.y;
    currentHealth = maxHealth;
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update () {

    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.5f, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1f, 1);
    }
}

public void TakeDamage(Vector3 hitPoint, int bulletDamage)
{
    // check that its Server so that damage only gets applied on the server
    if (!isServer)
    {
        return;
    }
    currentHealth -= bulletDamage;
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(painBodySound);
    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        currentHealth = 0;
        Debug.Log("Dead!");
    }
}
private void OnChangeHealth(int health)
{
    healthBar.sizeDelta = new Vector2(health, healthBar.sizeDelta.y);
}

}
```

Inside the bullet class is this function:

```
private void CastBulletRay()
{
    ray = new Ray(bulletSpawnPos, bulletSpawnDirection);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, bulletRayDistance))
    {
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Baddie")
        {
            Debug.Log("ray has hit a baddie");
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("ray has hit a player");
            hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().TakeDamage(hit.point, bulletDamage);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

and inside The Unity RigidBodyController class I'm using, I added:

```
    [Command]
    void CmdFireBullets()
    {
        muzzleFlashObject.SetActive(true);
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(gunFireSound, 0.2f);
        //Create a new bullet
        GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawnPoint.transform.position, bulletSpawnPoint.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

        //Spawn the bullet on the clients:
        NetworkServer.Spawn(newBullet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Far too much code. Remember that this site is intended not only to help you, but others with the same issue. This means the issue has to be concisely described and generally applicable. I suggest you start by duplicating the tutorial code exactly and seeing if the issue still exists.

Comment: well tbh i was going to post only what I thought was relevant, then I realised that this will probably not show up the problem if I only select the relevant code. But I will amend the question now to better suit the question recommendations.

Comment: @MichaelHouse how can I get this taken off 'Hold' please? I have revised the question to remove code I think was irrelevant to the question. Sidenote: I have had questions closed/suspended on this site because of the exact opposite (ie. I didnt include the full code in a question because i thought it wasnt relevant) anyways, thanks for looking, hope you can help.